# How to up a same compose when the comopse file location changed

Tags: docker, docker-compose

First I run `docker compose up -d` command under `/redis` folder.And a container with `ID 9c2223c1cde2` was created.
the `compose.yml` as fellow:

```
version: "3.7"
networks:
  wcs-network:
services:
  wcs-redis:
    container_name: wcs-redis
    image: redis:7.0.7
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    volumes:
      - ./config/redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
      - ./data:/data
    networks:
      - wcs-network
    privileged: true
    command: redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
```

When I was trying to refactoring my project, I moved this compose file to `/redis/file` folder. And changed container network in `compose.yml` as fellow:

```
version: "3.7"
networks:
  wcs-network2:
services:
  wcs-redis:
    container_name: wcs-redis
    image: redis:7.0.7
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    volumes:
      - ./config/redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
      - ./data:/data
    networks:
      - wcs-network2
    privileged: true
    command: redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
```

And I get an ERROR:
`Error response from daemon: Conflict. The container name "/wcs-redis" is already in use by container "9c2223c1cde2316a19f0db6b40c4eea66fc4d252676c74ed8a847572e58014e7". You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.`

I really want to know how to keep the same container when I change the `compose.yml` location and it's content.

Comment: You can do it easily if redis data was persisted in `./data` direxctory. First remove previous container and run this compose file again with correct volume path.

Answer (score 1):

Compose has the notion of a [project name](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/envvars/#compose_project_name) which has a couple of effects.  It is recorded in container metadata and used to construct the Docker-native names of various objects.

The default project name is constructed from the base name of the current directory.  When the Compose file was in `/redis` the project name defaulted to `redis`, but now that it is in `/redis/file` the default project name is `file`.  This means you effectively have two different Compose projects.  Since you override `container_name:` to a fixed string rather than let Compose choose its name, you get a conflict here.

You can delete the old setup by overriding the project name

```bash
docker-compose -p redis down -v
docker-compose up -d
```

(A corollary to this is that you don't need to include a project-specific prefix in the names in the Compose file itself.  You can also let Compose construct its `default` network, which will be unique per project, choose the `container_name:`, and choose an `image:` name for things you `build:`.  This can result in much shorter Compose files than you often see in SO questions.)

Comment: What if I want to change the volume mode from bind mount to volumes, and keep the date which in `./config/redis.conf` and `./data` . 
Because I need to change the compose.yml location. And I want to **reuse the same date from those old mounted floder in host.**

Comment: had to do the docker-compose up -d with additional flag --remove-orphans, and then everything worked, from this answer, in my case. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

first stop all previous containers and remove them. then run new container.

this error is because there is a container with name `/wcs-redis`. you can see it with `docker ps -a`.